# Handling response with raw data using RestKit

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I am using RestKit 0.23.3.

For a particular path pattern (say `download_data/:dataId`):

- I can send a request via RestKit without any problem,
- I expect a response with arbitrary Content Type (`image/png`, `text/plain`, `text/xml`,... or even `application/json`),
- If 2xx status code is returned by the server, I want to receive the body of HTTP response as NSData instance (regardless of Content Type) in the success handler block.

Is this possible (and how) using RestKit?

Thanks.

Comment: why RestKit?, you can easily use NSURLSession

Comment: I wonder if this can be accomplished using RestKit anyway as the framework may be useful to build the request even if it is an overkill for processing the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With new restkit 0.20.3 you can execute your rest web-service like:

```
[[AppDelegate appDelegate].rkomForProbeList getObjectsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:kResource_Probe,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kNS_DF_AccessRef]] parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
       NSLog(@"%@",operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString);
       // if raw data
 NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:NULL];
       // if mapped
       arrayForProbe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:mappingResult.array];             
   } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"%@",operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString);
        NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[,operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:NULL];

       NSLog(@"%@",operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode);
       NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
       [self hideViewContentAsProbesNotAvailable];
   }];
```

By mapping you will get your object directly from mappingarray. For parsing raw data you have get json object from response string.

rkomForProbeList is your RKObjectManager's instance. 
kResource_Probe is resource path. Like if base URL is http://www.hi.com/ and your rest api required http://www.hi.com/login then "login" will be your resource path.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what this code is doing. What are all the identifiers like `rkomForProbeList`, `kResource_Probe`?

Comment: Success handler is a nice place where you can access the HTTP response directly. However, if the response has content type e.g. image/jpeg, you must register a class that conforms to `RKSerialization` for this content type. Without registration of such class, the success handler is never reached and the response is considered to be an error by RestKit. The response can be processed (serialized) directly in this class that conforms to `RKSerialization` instead of success handler.

Comment: Anyway, I cannot probably prevent loading the whole response body to memory by RestKit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with RESTKit, but anyway maybe it will help you.
I suggest you to use `NSURLSession` for low level requests like this, as RESTKit adds a lot of abstractions, which is unnecessary for this task.

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourSite.com"]
                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
            if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300) {
                // that's OK
            } else {
                // something wrong
            }
        }
    }] resume];
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Of course, this is one option. However, I prefer using RestKit anyway. First, the app sends many different requests and RestKit is very helpful for most of them. I don't want an out of the box approach for this single one. Second, even if all the RestKit abstractions are odd for the reponse processing, they can be useful for sending the request.

Comment: RestKit is for mapping, if you aren't doing mapping of the response then you shouldn't use RestKit to make the request (though you could use RestKit to create a request that is sent by NSURLSession).